# Can I assign a value to a variable within a AND / OR sentence

Tags: javascript, short-circuit-evaluation

I haven't been able to find the keywords to find this question, because this has obviously been already answered, so I can only ask it again:

Can I assign a value to a variable like this? How could I express it to keep the one-line structure?

```js
let found = false
if (1) console.log('hi') && (found = true)
console.log(found) // it is still false
```

The real code is something like that

```
array.map(e => 
  condition_is_meet_with_e && 
  put_variables_in_a_complex_structure && 
  flag_that_the_condition_has_been_fulfilled <<== found = true
)
```

Comment: Because console.log() returns undefined, you can use `console.log('hi'), (found = true)`, which means left hand should be true for executing the next part i.e. `1 && true &&  (found = true)`

Comment: Yes, I have just figured it out, thanks!

Comment: Just write a non-shorthand function (i.e. use `{`, `}`, and `return`) so you can have straight forward `if` / `else` and readable code that won't confuse whoever has to maintain it in 6 months time (you'll be glad you did because that person will probably be future you).

Comment: Yes you can, but you absolutely shouldn't. (Unless you're playing code golf)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it works, but somehow `console.log` returns a false?

So, in this specific example, this is what works

```js
let found = false
if (1) console.log('hi') || (found = true)
console.log(found) // it is now true
```

And anything else should work as expected

```js
let found = false
let what = 1
console.log(found) // false
if (1) (what = 2) && (found = true)
console.log(found) // true
```